# 2 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') in reactjs with event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

What's the issue with my code ?

I've gotten two - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

expected behavior = click one button, the button uses class name red and calls function addValue if I click this button again it should call function removeValue and its color should change to white.

Instead I get this type error and every button is highlighted in red.

```
const [color, setColor] = useState(false)



function addValue(e) {
> 38 |     if (e.target.value !== "") {

  function removeValue(e, value) {
> 63 |   if (e.target.value !== "") {
```

These are the functions

```
function addValue(e) {
    if (e.target.value !== "") {
      
      if (!favs.includes(e.target.value)) {
        favs.push(e.target.value);
        localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(favs));
        console.log(favs);
        document.getElementById("favsarray").innerHTML =  favs
      }
    }
  }



function removeValue(e, value) {
    if (e.target.value !== "") {
      //delete from array
      favs.pop(e.target.value);
      console.log(favs);
      //change the div text
      document.getElementById("favsarray").innerHTML = favs;
      //get the values from localstorage- parse
      const stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name"));
      //delete the value
      delete stored[(value, e.target.value)];
      //store the new array as a string
      localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(favs));
      console.log(stored);
    }
  }
```

I am calling this function with this and an event handler

```
function addOrRemove(e) {
  const elem = e.currentTarget;
  setColor(!color)
if (color){
  addValue(elem)
} else {
  removeValue(elem)
}
}


<button
                id="btn"
                onClick={addOrRemove}
                className={color? "white": "red"}
                value={"Name:  " + d.name + "  Description:   " + d.description + "  Stars: " + d.stargazers_count + "  URL:   " + d.html_url}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to replace `e.target.value` in the two offending places with `e.value`.

This is because `e` is the argument to the function, which you're calling like this:

```
addValue(elem);
```

after

```
const elem = e.currentTarget;
```

where `e` is the argument to your event handler function. So `elem` is the DOM element that the event handler is currently firing on, therefore this is what `e` is inside the function. And DOM elements don't have a `target` property, but - if they're a button or input - they do have a `value` property.

It would also be clearer if you call the argument something like `elem` (which you use when you make the call) or `element` (in full) rather than `e`, which by convention is used for an event object, and may be what is confusing you here.

Comment: That fixed the error but the classname issue is still going on. Whatever button I select, they all the get the same class. It is storing the value correctly. But if I chose another button, it automatically removes the previous value.

Comment: sounds like a "stale closure" problem (google that term for more info) - try changing `setColor(!color)` to `setColor(color => !color)`. PS it looks like you have a lot still to learn about React, I don't know why you're explicitly setting `innerHTML` properties of elements here, you almost always don't need that in React.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I am still learning react. Thanks, I'll google that!